# Using Orchard how can I install/download/view a module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am using orchard 1.6
I am looking to download a completed module to have a look at the code.
D/L is available from https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Jfn7UoeC3FZ1E2NWVJc1NBVXc/edit?pli=1

How do I install the .nupkg as a module. Do i create the module as normal from the command line and some how copy it over?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unzip packages with 7zip (http://7-zip.org/) and add them to your modules folder.

Or you can go to the admin -> modules -> features -> install from computer and upload your package there